# Can trying(the v-ing of try)be a subject of the sentence?

Tags: subjects

We know that "try" as a verb has its noun form "try" that can be the subject of a sentence, but is there
any chance that "trying" can also be the subject? For example,"constant trying can help us..." Is it
correct in grammar? Do we use it like that in daily life?

Comment: Yes, a gerund can be used like a noun (_Cycling is my favourite form of exercise_).

Comment: Yes: gerund-participial clauses can function as subject, In your example "trying " is a noun by virtue of it being premodified by the adjective "constant" (adjectives cannot modify verbs). It is to be distinguished from the verb form in "constantly trying ...", where it has adverbial premodification and thus must be a verb.

Answer (score 1):

A gerund is a noun formed from a verb so you can use it when you would have used a noun

> Trying to learn English is making my brain hurt
> I failed but it was not for want of trying

are just a couple of examples

If you put *gerund sentence subject* into your favourite search engine you should get many other examples.

Comment: Actually, gerunds are verbs that function like nouns, but are not actually nouns themselves. The real nouns formed by conversion from _ing_ verbs are called 'gerundial nouns', or just nouns. Compare "They were criticised for **killing** the seals" (verb form) ~ They had witnessed the **killing** of the seals" (noun form).

Comment: True. Gerunds are verbs still; but _trying_ could just as easily be a noun as a gerund. Unless there's an object, it's hard to tell. If you can put an article in front of it, it's a noun -- _The trying took longer than the actual work._